# mask: the extension doesn't recognize included backend layouts

Tags: typo3, tx-mask

when using the extension mask and including my backend layouts via

`<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:fileadmin/jweilandnet_musterprojekt/Resources/TSConfig/" extensions="ts">`

mask doesn't recognize my backend layouts.

is there a way to do this?

If i create my backend layouts in a sys folder ist normally works.
it is a requirement form the customer to inlcude all files from external

best regards Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask doesn't support file based backend layouts at the moment. But the feature is on its way and will make it into production in the next version (2.2.0).